How to Apply Animation/Transition Effect in MudBlazor .Net6.0
Code Below is the Reference for Animation/Transition Effect I wanted.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px; /* Set the width of the container */
  height: 100px; /* Set the height of the container */
}

.div-with-animation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px; /* Start width */
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  animation: expand-contract 4s infinite; /* Apply the animation with looping */
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Define the animation */
@keyframes expand-contract {
  0% {
    width: 10px; /* Start width */
  }
  50% {
    width: 1000px; /* End width */
  }
  100% {
    width: 10px; /* Back to start width */
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="div-with-animation"></div>
   <div class="text">
     <h1>The CSS Animation</h1>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Code Below is My MudBlazor Code where I wanted Animation/Transition Effect As Like Above Html code .
<style> 
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px; /* Set the width of the container */
  height: 100px; /* Set the height of the container */
}

.div-with-animation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px; /* Start width */
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  animation: expand-contract 4s infinite; /* Apply the animation with looping */
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Define the animation */
@keyframes expand-contract {
  0% {
    width: 10px; /* Start width */
  }
  50% {
    width: 1000px; /* End width */
  }
  100% {
    width: 10px; /* Back to start width */
  }
}
</style>
<div class="container">
   <div class="div-with-animation"></div>
<div class="text">
<MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle1"><b>Quick Actions</b></MudText>
</div>
 </div>

Here I want that lightblue background color to start from 0% width and move till 100% width in loop.
But it's Showing Error As

Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  CS0103  The name 'keyframes' does not exist in the current context  UIDesignRisk.Client


Gotta try something first. If that doesn't work, post it here and you'll receive help.

Yes. I tried to create same effect using css but  @keyframes is not supporting for  mudblazor

It seems like you have to use @@ instead of @
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26704
